# Update IntelliJ (macOS) for Java SDK 9

Tags: java, intellij-idea, upgrade, java-9

I just downloaded Java SDK 9 for Mac and installed it:
Console output:

```
felixbreuer$ java -version
java version "9"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9+181)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9+181, mixed mode)
```

But when I wanna do a new Project or change the Java SDK Version of my current Project in IntelliJ I can only choose the Module Java 1.8 ...
Anybody knows how I can upgrade this ? I bet its easy but I can't find any solutions on the web... they only show the new features for java 9 in IntelliJ to its 100% supported.

Comment: your intelliJ version?

Comment: IntelliJ Ultimate 2017.2.5

Comment: You have to tell IntelliJ where you installed JDK 9, it will not see it automatically. See documentation: [Working with SDKs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-sdks.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the new JDK, in order to let IntelliJ make use of it.

```
Project Settings -> Project SDK -> New -> Add new JDK -> Select the path to JDK9's Content/Home
```

[image]